# Rotate Squared Matrix java solution: Why it works?

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix

I want to solve the following problem: You are given an n x n 2D matrix representing an image.
Rotate the image by 90 degrees (clockwise) in-place. I found one very nice solution here: http://n00tc0d3r.blogspot.de/2013/05/rotate-image.html Namely,

```
     public void rotate(int[][] matrix) {  
   for (int level = 0, len = matrix.length; level < len; ++level, --len) {  
     int end = len - 1;  
     for (int pos = level; pos < end; ++pos) {  
       int tail = matrix.length - pos - 1;  

       int tmp = matrix[level][pos];  
       // left -> top  
       matrix[level][pos] = matrix[tail][level];  
       // bottom -> left  
       matrix[tail][level] = matrix[end][tail];  
       // right -> bottom  
       matrix[end][tail] = matrix[pos][end];  
       // top -> right  
       matrix[pos][end] = tmp;  
     }  
   }  
 }
```

I see that it works, and I understand the idea, but my question is why we use `++level` instead of `level++` and why we use `--len` instead of `len--`. I tried both was and it worked fine for me. However for such problems (non trivial matrix traversal) people always use `++level` instead of `level++`. Again my question is **why**?

Comment: I guess because they felt like it.

Comment: [Related question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/59880/avoid-postfix-increment-operator) - I think there is no difference at all, likely it's all about coding style

Answer (score 2):

Consider this :

```
i = 0;
System.out.println(i++); // postfix increment
```

This prints 0, but `i` is updated to 1 as you expect.

```
i = 0;
System.out.println(++i); // prefix increment
```

This prints 1.

From [Java Langauge Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.1),

> The value of the postfix increment expression is the value of the variable *before* the new value is stored.

And

> The value of the prefix increment expression is the value of the variable *after* the new value is stored.

In your case of a `for` loop, it does not make a difference on which one you use, but it's really a matter of choice and habit.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between using `++level` or `level++` / `--len` or `len--` in an *increment/decrement* part of the `for` loop. The `len` or `level` values are not used in that section of the loop. so, the values are going to be very same after the execution of that part of the for loop. It is just programmer's decision. That's all

Answer (score 0):

`++level` is evaluated after the increment and `level++` before. The difference is subtle.
As the values of `++level` and `++len` aren't used in any expressions it's just a matter of style.

Answer (score 0):

It does not have any effect in this "for" loop, but the prefix operator is applied before evaluation of the expression it is used within and the suffix operator after evaluation.

An example where it would make a difference is

```
while (i++ < 5)
{
  foo(bar);
}
```

or

```
while (++i < 5)
{
  foo(bar);
}
```

(The former one will go through one additional iteration compared to the latter one since it increments after evaluation of the comparison)